# How to bind GreenSock Draggable to an SVG element, but have the effects apply to another element?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, gsap

I am attempting to use GreenSock to make an SVG interactive. This is the basic structure of the SVG:

```
                ---------------------------------
----------------|------------------------|      |
|               |                        |      |
|       B       |      <----->           |  A   |
|               |                        |      |
----------------|------------------------|      |
                ---------------------------------
```

Where A is the `svg` container, and B is a `g` element within it.
I want to be able to retrieve drag event information from the `svg` A, and apply them to the `g` element B, so that the `svg` element does not move, but the `g` element B slides back and forth inside the `svg` - with momentum effects using the `ThrowPropsPlugin`. There are two reasons for this:

- I want the user to be able to drag anywhere on the `svg` and get the effect.
- I can't apply an event listener to the `g` element.

I am not sure how to do this using GreenSock. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to do this?

Note that I do have access to the GreenSock Business library, so I have the `ThrowPropsPlugin` available.

Comment: just a thought, but try looking into nesting svgs. put the `g` inside an svg thats inside the main svg container. then add a listener to the second svg.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Is the SVG embedded in the page HTML? Or have you added it using an `<img>` element?